# I need to delay the rigid body on a cell fractured object. How?

Tags: animation, add-on, rigid-body-simulation

I need to delay a cell fractured object collapse and I can do it with one cell but I cant "Copy From Active" the "Animated" Checkbox.. I really need to and I dont have time to do each one individually. [image: I have the delayed cell selected in the picture.]

Comment: Have you tried animating the *Dynamic* checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

"Copy to selected" on "animated" checkbox works fine for me.  Select two objects, RMB on the checkbox, copy to selected.

You can also apply checkbox operations to multiple selected objects by using alt LMB.  Select one box, select another box, move to rigid body tab, alt-LMB on animated.

Answer (score 0):

Start by animating the checkbox on one object. Select every object that needs to share the animation and make sure your animated object is active.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and choose "Animation Data". This will link the animation from the active object to every selected object.