# Attributing "active" type to object during animation

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

An object is suspended above a plane. Halfway the animation I want it to suddenly become an "**active**" body, so that it drops down under the influence of gravity, ending with bouncing on the plane.

However, apparently it is impossible to keyframe "type" (under the Rigid Body tab). In this case it would need to change from "passive" to "active".

Any solutions?

Comment: Keyframe up to ... then Animate the "Animated" switch... or change the start frame of the rigid body world.  Sure there is a similar (or same) answer. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81106/i-need-to-delay-the-rigid-body-on-a-cell-fractured-object-how